# Sprite Color palette swap in Pixel Shader

Tags: c++, directx-11, fragment-shader

I am in the making of a sprite based fighting game, and development has come to a point, that I want to implement color swapping of images during runtime (so a user can specify through an interface, what exact color should be changed to what, and it would be done in an instant, whithout any interruption by a loading screen). 
I figured it would be quite easily achieved in the pixel shader. I tried it out, by setting the values to change specifically an other color, and it worked quite well. 
For the next step I wanted to make it to read out the data from a text file (containing the color codes of the color to change and then the color to change to). It has several entries, and it is stored in an array like this:

```
XMFLOAT3 palette[10][2];
```

And here is the corresponding constant entry in the shader:

```
float4 xPalette[10][2];
```

What this means, it stores 10 colors to change and 10 colors to change those to. I pass this to the Pixel Shader via a constant buffer, and it does not work as planned, because only the array's last entry is recognised, all the others are zeroes. I think it would be because the 16-bit alignation before sending data to the GPU? What other method is there to send data like this to the pixel shader? 
Thank you for reading through this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send your swaps as a texture itself, with maybe the top row of texels being the ones you want to replace, with [x][y+1] as the color you want to change it to. (Since texture coordinates range from 0 to 1 you'd probably have to pass, as an integer, the number of colors you're replacing then you could index with (1/replaceCount*i). GLSL lets you pass textures with sampler2D's I think. I imagine it's similar with HLSL (been a few months since I wrote HLSL though. :( )

Then you could just sample/compare each texel in the top row during your shader.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've already been thinking of texture maps for this, and such textures would be probably easy to created by the developer, but I would not know how to create textures during runtime (for I am trying to make an editor for the colors as well), so I tried to do a more flexible approach (for me that is). I'm guessing it is totally doable, so time to look up the web. 
Again, thank you for the reply!

Comment: [This is one way to pragmatically create your texture, if you're interested in doing so.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802205/creating-texture-programmatically-directx)

Comment: Thank you, hovewer, i've got it figured out, it was yet again the problem with the 16-bit alignation kicking in (and me not noticing arrgh, happened so many times). I thought, by declarig, and sending XMFLOAT3 arrays to the pixel shader, would send 4-element floats, with the last element zeroed (as it does with a single one passed). Hovewer, for I was sending arrays of them, it would mess up the whole, because the last element (which I thought would be zero) is replaced by the first element of the next entry, and screwing up the whole structure. I noticed it by Printscreen and sampling colors.